# Project working on one computer but not the other

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

My ruby project is working fine on one of my Macbooks, but on the other I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    13: from bin/audiobook-now:5:in `<main>'
    12: from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/Development/code/audiobook-now-cli/lib/cli.rb:50:in `run'
    11: from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/Development/code/audiobook-now-cli/lib/cli.rb:7:in `get_books_from'
    10: from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/Development/code/audiobook-now-cli/lib/scraper.rb:7:in `scrape_book_list'
     9: from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:274:in `visit'
     8: from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/poltergeist-1.18.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:100:in `visit'
     7: from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/poltergeist-1.18.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:27:in `browser'
     6: from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/poltergeist-1.18.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:47:in `client'
     5: from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/poltergeist-1.18.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client.rb:16:in `start'
     4: from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/poltergeist-1.18.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client.rb:16:in `new'
     3: from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/poltergeist-1.18.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client.rb:53:in `initialize'
     2: from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/cliver-0.3.2/lib/cliver.rb:24:in `detect!'
     1: from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/cliver-0.3.2/lib/cliver/dependency.rb:116:in `detect!'
/Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/cliver-0.3.2/lib/cliver/dependency.rb:143:in `raise_not_found!': Could not find an executable ["phantomjs"] on your path. (Cliver::Dependency::NotFound)
```

I had been getting similar problems at various points and most of the fixes were in the code (some `require` statements were looping around to each other), but the program works on my other Macbook without these errors. Their repos are synced, I've even tried looking at the code to make sure they're identical. I've also used `bundle list` to compare the versions of the gems and they match. Here's the gemfile, in case it's helpful.

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-rescue' 
gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
gem 'pry-nav'
gem 'poltergeist'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'require_all'
```

Both Macbooks are running the same version of Mojave and I don't *think* there's anything different about the systems that would cause this. They should all be on the same version of gems and bundlers etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
/Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/cliver-0.3.2/lib/cliver/dependency.rb:143:in `raise_not_found!': Could not find an executable ["phantomjs"] on your path. (Cliver::Dependency::NotFound)
```

explains why your project does not work on another computer.

Gem `poltergeist` is a PhantomJS driver for Capybara. To make it work you need to install `phantomjs` (a headless browser). You could download it from PhantomJS official site:

http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Make sure you're installing the same version. To do so run this command in Terminal of 1st Macbook:

```
phantomjs -v
```

to find out the installed version, and install the same version on the 2nd Macbook.

Comment: Thank you Ilya! I've got phantomjs installed now, but now I get `.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- poltergeist (LoadError)`. But `bundle install` lists `poltergeist (1.18.1)` although `poltergeist -v` says command not found.

Comment: As [gem documentation](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) suggests, it can be loaded with `require ‘capybara/poltergeist’`. Check in Rails console if this command work.

Comment: Thanks Ilya. I did have that in my environment. Somehow, though, it's all working now even though I don't think I changed anything. But I'm sure installing phantomjs as you suggested helped! Thanks!